# What are the angles of a triangle which shares points with a regular pentagon adjacent to a square? [Image]

Tags: geometry, triangles, polygons

My cousin had a geometry homework question, which asked to find the angles of [a triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDvXJ.jpg) inside the [following shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd3ik.jpg)

That was fairly simple. (The angles are 45, 54, and 81 degrees because both are regular polygons.)

I was wondering what would happen if the triangle instead was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOnbr.jpg)

What would its angles be? I only know that angle ACG is 117 degrees; the other two seem to require some abstruse trigonometry work to calculate.

Comment: The angle seems to be non-special. If you don't want to use trigonometry such as sine-law and arc-sin functions then I think there is no way to get the angles. $GAC=45$ will imply $AE=EG$ which is obviously false. Using trigonometry I found $AGC=25.7, GAC=37.3$.

Comment: @cr001 Can you post an answer showing how you arrived at those values?

Comment: Yes I will post an answer about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a perpendicular line $AH$ to $FG$, let $AC=x$.

Then $AH=x+{1\over2}x\cdot tan(72)=({1\over2}tan(72)+1)x$.

Hence $AGF=arctan({({1\over2}tan(72)+1)x\over{1\over2}x})=78.86$.

$AGE=90-78.86=11.14$, $AGC=11.14+9=20.14$ and $GAC=180-117-20.14-=42.86$

An alternative way will be use pythagorean theorem to get $AG=\sqrt{({1\over2}tan(72)+1)^2x^2+({1\over2}x)^2}$ and use since law where $AGC=arcsin({AC\over({AG\over sin(117)})})$ you still get $AGC=20.14$ here.

I am sorry this is different from the comment, I must have entered something wrong into wolfram alpha.